# Help with Calculating Probability for a Normal Distribution Question

Tags: probability

I am currently working on a question about normal distribution and I am having some trouble calculating the probability. I was wondering if anyone could help me out?

The question is as follows:

The weight of bicycles in a certain shop is normally distributed with a standard deviation of $2.2 \mathrm{~kg}$ and a mean weight of $15 \mathrm{~kg}$. Calculate the probability that a randomly selected bicycle from the shop weighs over $20 \mathrm{~kg}$.

Here is my attempt at solving the question:

Let X be the weight of a randomly selected bicycle from the shop. We know that X follows a normal distribution with a mean of $\mu = 15 \mathrm{~kg}$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma = 2.2 \mathrm{~kg}$.

We are interested in finding $P(X > 20)$. To calculate this, we need to standardize X using the formula:

$z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$

Substituting the given values, we get:

$z = \frac{20 - 15}{2.2} \approx 2.27$

Now we need to find the probability that a standard normal random variable Z is greater than 2.27. Using a table or a calculator, we find that this probability is approximately $0.011$.

Therefore, the probability that a randomly selected bicycle from the shop weighs over $20 \mathrm{~kg}$ is approximately $0.011$.

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the trouble ?

Comment: @Kurt G. I’m just unsure over how my calculations stack up against a benchmark, is there anything I can do to verify the accuracy of my calculations? Also, what do you think about this solution: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/702802823032733859/1087157704373571637/image0.jpg

Comment: If you are of the opinion that 0.01152
 is approximately 0.011
 I am not going to argue with you. A more acceptable version with two significant decimals is to round 0.01152
 this up to 0.012.
 BTW: are you aware that every normal CDF calculation is always approximate? There is no elementary function that gives us the integral, except for the bounds −∞
 and +∞.
 – 
K

Comment: @KurtG. I’m not sure I followed you on the last sentence.. is it possible if you could elaborate?

Comment: Except for the inegration bounds $x_0=-\infty,x_1=0$ or $x_0=0,x_1=+\infty$ or $x_0=-\infty,x_1=+\infty$ I do not know of an exact solution of $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx\,.$ In practice we always only have an approximation for this integral, albeit a very accurate one.